# How to change language of one2many field in Odoo10

Tags: translation, one-to-many, odoo, odoo-10

i have a problem related to one2many field. I'm working on sale order form and my customer language is chinese. And i want that when i'm add a product from sale order line than sale order line model should show in chinese language('partner_id.lang). For this i added context('lang') of partner language. but still not getting expected result. Means sale order form should show in english language and sale order line will be shows in chinese language(customer language). So, how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I need to see your code

Comment: <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="context">
                    "{'lang': 'zh_HK', 'default_lang': 'zh_HK' }"
            </attribute>
 </xpath>

Comment: Try to add with_context( lang = partner.lang )  to get product name in onchange product.